# How do I find the new coordinates of a rotated Cuboid[]?

Tags: graphics3d

How do I find the new coordinates of a rotated `Cuboid[]`, obtained through

```
GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[],RotationTransform[-Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}]]
```

`CoordinateBounds` does not seem to work

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer myself.

If you want the transformed cube to be again a region so that you can use `CoordinateBounds` you should use `TransformedRegion` as follows:

```
TransformedRegion[Cuboid[],RotationTransform[-Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}]]
```

now `CoordinatessBounds` works properly.